# First story having both the bad guys and the good guys avoiding using weapons in a space craft or space station that would puncture hull?

Tags: history-of, spaceship, space, space-station

It seems like this comes up a lot: despite the bad guys having murderous intent, there is at least a tacit agreement not to use projectile weapons or anything else that would make a hole in the ship's hull and cause disastrous decompression.

I assume there have also been stories in which even the good guys out of desperation threaten to cause decompression, sort of the Mutually Assured Destruction that seems to be part of the real-life "defense" plans for some countries.

Comment: I suspect that this question is futile; the 1930s were the age of the ray gun and other exotic weapons, and many of them, used in space, would not have damaged the hull.  For example, Hamilton's "pain ray" (1928), a "poisoned needle-gun" (Cloukey, 1931), Ashton Clark Smith's "zero-ray" (1931), Weinbaum's "glass pistol" (1934), Cumming's "Banning gun" (1938) and so on.  There are stun rays, paralysis beams, Heinlein had a ray that caused epileptic convulsions...  Then there are death beams, rays and others that ignore structures and just kill people...

Comment: And on the other side of the question, up into the 1940s most space ships are built like battleships, and small arms aren't going to affect them.  Even when lighter ships appear, most are dealt with realistically enough that a small meteor puncture is a patchable, survivable event.  It makes no sense for a spaceship to rapidly decompress from a bullet-sized hole.

Comment: @DavidW: But some stories do have fear that using a weapon will penetrate the hull. Obviously, where weapons don't penetrate the hull, there would not be this plot element. A ray gun, in real life a laser certainly melts through metal. Poison darts would be a great weapon for space that would allow both sides to happily kill each other. The soviets equipped their cosmonauts with shotguns (for wolves, not space wolves but real ones)  which at least in the Lunar Lander would be unusualable (against space wolves). I think we also gave our guys weapons even though we say we did not. Maybe not.

Comment: Our guys landed in water, making the use of guns less effective, especially against wolves.

Comment: In the Lensman series boarding troops use axes, but if I recall correctly that is not so much to avoid decompression as because Axes are awesome.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I reckon NASA decided that if we ran into aliens, lupine or not, shooting them might just make them destroy humanity, even as various countries said, No, just destroy the Americans -- we did not do nothing. But I still would not be surprised if arming the astronauts was done anyway or at least contemplated. At some point I am afraid space travelers will be armed against other human space travelers. Landing in water btw has no bearing on effectiveness of guns against wolves. Just likelihood of encountering wolves.

Comment: @EikePierstorff: seems to me that axes would indeed be chosen as a weapon that would be safer to use. Did both sides use axes? Because what's the point if your enemies use guns?

Comment: @releseabe I have to look where I put the books to see how this is described exactly. But I think both parties used axes not instead of, but in addition to guns, which would invalidate the point.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Maybe axes used for situations where they are near the outer hull so by agreement they fight in this  way although if my opp had better reach I would use the gun anyway and just make sure I hit his body. I mean, how thin are hulls anyway?

Comment: @releseabe: https://caseknives.com/collections/astronaut-knife#:~:text=The%20original%20Case%20Astronaut%20Knife,space%20mission%20led%20by%20NASA.

I remember reading about them as a kid.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: Just "in case" there are space wolves. If any knife would scare a lupine alien, that would. I bet the astronauts were desperately hoping some alien would start stuff. Or another astronaut snored or something. Or they could show them off at the ISS and maybe someone would cheat at bridge.

Comment: @releseabe: More details at https://gizmodo.com/this-moon-machete-didnt-turn-me-into-an-astronaut-but-1836055424 and probably other places, but it seems the justification was entirely terrestrial survival, although knives are often good multipurpose tools, and I'm of the belief that it's better to have and not need than need and not have.

Comment: To be clear you want the first story that uses a weapons deliberately designed not to pierce the spaceship hull.. As opposed to not being able to pierce the spaceship hull unintentionally?

Comment: Lensmen is out. They use axes because armor blocks guns and energy beams, not because they worry about decompression (in fact, in seems they use axes to cause quite a lot of compression, albeit in context this is a secondary cause of death at the most).

Comment: Would an airship count?  It seems like, at least one Doc Savage story had a "daren't shoot because airship" incident.

Comment: @A.B.: Okay. There are also probably stories where both sides have to be quiet because of another danger, etc.